# use multiple responsive layouts with bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

if we use bootstrap 3, we can write

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
</div>
<div>
```

but how to do the same in bootstrap 4? I tried with `<div class="col-6 col-12">` but it only works as col-lg-12 (full width). I need to use same div with different classes like in BS3, in BS4. how can I do that?

Comment: it is same for BS4. except there is no xs devices and have xl devices and so they rearranged a little. Yo can go through grid option section in both [BS3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options) and [BS4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#grid-options) to see the differences.

Comment: so if I use *sm* instead of *xs*, will it be the same? similarly can I use *sm* equal to *md* and *lg*equal to *xl*?

Comment: you just need to put `col-12 col-lg-6` in your case

Comment: Go through the documentation and play with those classes by doing demos then you can understand how it is used

Comment: will do. thanks a  lot

Answer (score 1):

Your example in BS3:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    </div>
<div>
```

BS4 version:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    </div>
<div>
```

In the above code below medium devices, it will be full width (12 cols) as that's the default.

In medium-sized devices and above it will be 6 cols wide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `col-12 col-md-6` as your classes.

Comment: didnt work. I think col-12 overrides col-md-6 all the time.

Comment: From what resolution you want your element to take half of the width? As BS4 grid (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options) has different breakpoints than BS3